# HTTP Error fetching URL. Status=400

Tags: jsoup

JSoup seems to work with just about all URLs I've tried but this one gives me the 400 error.

```
String url = "http://localad.walmart.com?storeref=3008&forceview=y";

Response response = Jsoup.connect(url.replaceAll(" ", "%20"))
    .method(Method.GET)
    .userAgent("Mozilla")
    .followRedirects(false)
    .timeout(5000)
    .data("pragma", "no-cache")
    .execute();
```

Error I get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=400, URL=http://localad.walmart.com?storeref=3008&forceview=y&pragma=no-cache
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:449)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:424)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:178)
```

Comment: can you help with that situation? Do you have answer?

Answer (score 3):

It is a little annoying when JSoup throws a fatal exception on a 400 Bad Request as this completely terminates any process running, even when wrapped in a try/catch. But hey.

There is a solution to this, on your initial connection URL, append the method;

```
.ignoreHttpErrors(true)
```

For example;

```
Jsoup.connect(url).ignoreHttpErrors(true).execute().statusCode();
```

Which then gives you the official '400' status code rather than throwing a fatal exception.

I know this is an old post, but posting for reference as I came across this thread while looking for a solution to this exact thing.

Answer (score 0):

400 is Bad Request.

You should try `URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8")` instead of using `replaceAll`.

Comment: I did try that but because the URL has no protocol that throws a MalformedURLException

Answer (score 0):

Moved on without relying on JSoup for resolving the intermediate (redirected URL). I needed the final redirect URL (which JSoup had no problems working with), so used the following code to get that.

```
import java.net.URI;
import org.apache.http.HttpRequest;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.ProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRedirectStrategy;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;

public class MyRedirectHandler extends DefaultRedirectStrategy {

    public URI lastRedirectedUri;

    @Override
    public boolean isRedirected(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, 
        HttpContext context) {
    try {
        return super.isRedirected(request, response, context);
     } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
    }

    @Override
    public URI getLocationURI(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, HttpContext context)
        throws ProtocolException {

        lastRedirectedUri = super.getLocationURI(request, response, context);
        return lastRedirectedUri;
    }
```

Invoking code:

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String url2 = "http://localad.walmart.com/walmart/new_user_entry.aspx?storeref=3008&forceview=y";
    MyRedirectHandler handler = new MyRedirectHandler();
    httpclient.setRedirectStrategy(handler);

    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url2);
    httpclient.execute(get);

    String lastUrl = url2;
    if (handler.lastRedirectedUri != null) {
        lastUrl = handler.lastRedirectedUri.toString();
    }
```